# Two claims principal in one request in ASP.NET Core

Tags: asp.net-core, authentication, claims

We can access `ClaimsPrincipal` for current request from `HttpContext.User`. As it seems to me, the `AuthenticateResult.Success()` in custom handler sets `HttpContext.User` to the created `ClaimsPrincipal`. And that's the problem.

I use cookie authentication scheme to authenticate users and custom authentication scheme to authenticate clients.

There are scenarios, where client redirects user to my app and then I have to authenticate client that redirected the user and then the user which is redirected.

So after successful client authentication, I create authentication ticket and `ClaimsPrincipal` is cached in `HttpContext.User`. In next step, I authenticate user. And what's now? Currently existing client's `ClaimsPrincipal` is overriden by user's `ClaimsPrincipal` and I lose info about authenticated client.

So how can I have multiple `ClaimsPrinciapl` for `HttpContext`? Or is there another, better solution?

Answer (score 0):

You can using below code when login.

```
HttpContext.Authentication.SignInAsync("Cookie", userPrincipal1,
new AuthenticationProperties
{
    ExpiresUtc = DateTime.UtcNow.AddMinutes(20),
    IsPersistent = false,
    AllowRefresh = false
});
```

When you want add another ClaimsPrincipal, you can use the code below.

```
var userPrincipal2= new ClaimsPrincipal(new ClaimsIdentity(new[]
{
    new Claim(ClaimTypes.Name, "Jason"),
    new Claim(ClaimTypes.Role, "User"),
}));
httpContext.User.AddIdentity(userPrincipal2.Identity);
```

ClaimsPrincipal objects with multiple identities are referred to as "complex identities". You can use the [HasClaim](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.security.claims.claimsprincipal.hasclaim?view=net-7.0) method to check if a claim is present in any of the identities.

Comment: It could work but seems bad approach to me. Because I dont want one 'ClaimsPrincipal' with many identities because user and client identity are different things in my app. What's more, the client authenticates per request and there is no any session. User has cookie or session.